# Сломанная кодировка StandardOutput.ReadLine C#

Tags: c#, кодировка, cmd

я хочу исполнить bat скрипт с перехватом вывода консоли, используя этот код

`

```
            Process proc = new Process();
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"path\to\.bat";
            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"path\to'dir";
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.Start();

            string ConOut = "";

            do
            {
                ConOut = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                if (ConOut != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ConOut);
                }

            } while (ConOut != null);
```

`

на выходе получается кирилица, но если я использую тот же самый код внутри WPF приложения, то `proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();` выдает ЌҐў®§¬®¦­®, в обоих случаях код запускается из другого потока

Comment: Ну потому что у консоли кодировка `cp866`, а у виндовых программ `cp1251`, наверное в этом дело. Где-то нужно указывать кодировку.

Comment: вот я и не знаю где, нашел способ с  `var stream = p.StandardOutput.BaseStream;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(866)))
{
    string r = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}`
он рабочий, но мне не подходит, потому что логи должны быть по мере выполнения

Comment: Попробуйте задать `proc.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866)` или что-то типа того https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.standardoutputencoding

Comment: Да, сработало, спасибо

Comment: Тогда оформлю ответом )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо, это потому, что у консоли кодировка `cp866`, а у виндовых программ `cp1251`. Где-то нужно указывать кодировку. Попробуйте так:

```
proc.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866)
```

Comment: провайдера еще зарегать надо, если конечно это не фреймворк 4